# How to Compress video file in android

Tags: android, video, compression

I want to compress video file before uploading to server.I gone through this link 
[How to compress a video to maximum level android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002163/how-to-compress-a-video-to-maximum-level-android), but i did not get an answer. Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try

```
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));     
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(690000 );
```

Comment: I have videos in my sdcard i want to compress this already existing file before uploading

Comment: @Divya then do it using FFMPEG.

Click [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) for reference

Answer (score 4):

We can compress video using ffmpeg in android.

For integrating FFmpeg in android we can use precompiled libraries like [ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android).

You can use below command to compress video

```
String[] command = {"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-s", "160x120", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

Here,

**-y**

Overwrite output files without asking.

**-i**

ffmpeg reads from an arbitrary number of input “files” specified by the -i option

**-s**

video output size

**-r**

Set frame rate

**-vcodec**

Set the video codec.

**-b:v**

Set the video bitrate

**-b:a**

Set the audio bitrate

**-ac**

Set the number of audio channels.

**-ar**

sets the sampling rate for audio streams if encoded

For detailed explanation and code on using ffmpeg in android to edit videos,check out below ffmpeg video editor tutorial link on my blog which includes compressing video using ffmpeg-

https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ffmpeg lib to compress your video:-

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec mp2 output.mp4
```

Comment: Can you suggest an example??